# Recover several values contain in an object c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, display, data-recovery

I start event in my button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 _info.Event(value,data); // _info declared above for call from other class
 _info.Event(value2,data2);
}
```

My Form:

```
public Form1()
{
 _info = new Info();
 _info.NewData += CustomEvent;
}
```

And for display:

```
private void CustomEvent(object sender, MyEvent e)
{
 textBox1.Text = (e.data).ToString();
 textBox2.Text = (e.data).ToString(); //only this value show in both textboxs
}
```

My question is: I try to use my event for recover several values but i don't know how to separate values in my object for display them in different textboxs?

Comment: Why not using delegates?

Comment: @AdrianEffort So how?

Comment: I posted a solution. Go take a look

Comment: See [mcve]. You are not following guidelines and your question is unclear (you don't show input, output and what you expect exactly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example on how to work with [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/):
*Of corse you can change the params in the delegate. I chose "string data" & "bool success", but you can change them.*

---

```
public class Foo
{
    public delegate void MyDataDelegate(string data, bool success); //create a delegate (=custom return/param type for event)
    public event MyDataDelegate OnMyEvent; //create event from the type of the early created delegate

    private void myMethod()
    {
        //do something 
        bool success = true;
        OnMyEvent?.Invoke("some data", success); //invoke event (use "?" to check if it is null). Pass the params
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyClass
{
    Foo myFoo;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myFoo = new Foo();
        myFoo.OnMyEvent += OnMyEventtriggered; //subscribe to the event in the costructor of your class
    }

    private void OnMyEventtriggered(string data, bool success)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how it can help me for separate values from an object?

Comment: If you pass X different values you won't have to separate them. @NewCSharpWork

Comment: It doesnt work, maybe because i have a customevent.

Comment: OnMyEvent is also a custom event. it should work... Whats the error/problem? @NewCSharpWork

Comment: No overload for 'MyEvent' does not match to delegate 'EventHandler<RandomEvent>' , and this randomevent is nowhere in my code...

Comment: Where do you get the "EventHandler<RandomEvent>"? Just copy paste the code above... @NewCSharpWork

Comment: At line `Foo.OnMyEvent += OnmyEventtriggered;` i got error message i said above.

Comment: You got different forms/windows right? I edited the answer. (Foo is your other from/window object) @NewCSharpWork

Comment: Yes MyEvent is call from DLL.Of course i used my own names for all lines.

Comment: No but my error is probably from files link or something like that so i assumed your answer is working. Thanks you for help.